# Stopping and resuming timer in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two solutions. The first of them using the method `animate`:

http://jsfiddle.net/g9aK8/3/

The problem is with a delay, when we pause timer for example on 400px and resume then we have to wait again all delay (the speed of bar is absolutely lower).

In the second solution I used `interval`:

http://jsfiddle.net/6wNcd/1/

It looks better, but when I tried stop this after a few minutes I had to wait something about 30 seconds then stopped. I not sure that using here `interval` with that small value is correct.

Have you any ideas how do this smartly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this jquery code i tested it and it's working fine

```
$('#button').hover(function() {
    $(this).text('pause');
    $('#bar').stop();
}, function() {
    $(this).text('play');
    var w=$('#bar').css('width');
    var val=parseInt((6000*(500-parseInt(w))/500));
    $('#bar').animate({width: '500px'}, val, 'linear', function() {
        $('#bar').css('width', '0px');                      
    });
});
​​
```

Answer (score 0):

If your first example, whenever you restart the animation, you are always setting a 2 second animation, even if there are only a few pixels more to animate, thus it appears to go slowly.  If you want it to continue at the same rate when you restart it, you will have to scale the time for how much remaining distance there is in the animation.

Here's a fixed version of the first example that scales the time by how much it has left:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'play') {
        $(this).text('pause');
        var box$ = $('#box');
        var left = parseInt(box$.css("left"), 10) || 0;
        box$.animate({ left:'150px' }, 2000 * ((150 - left) / 150), 'linear');
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('play')
        $('#box').stop();
    }
})
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TVg7x/

From your two options, I would select the first version because the second version leaves an interval timer running, even when the animation is stopped which isn't a good idea for CPU utilization, especially on mobile.

Comment: So if you had to implement that you choose first example, right?